# SQL Sum Group by Custom Group

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have generated the following query, and I want to sum the patient counts by the new IMS_CUST_ID_GRP I created (roll it up to this a remove the CUST_ID) in my query.  How can i modify my query to return my desired result?  I tried using an analytic function but I get an error.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)   = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)  >=2 AND SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) <=12 THEN '2-12'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) >=13 AND SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)<=24 THEN '13-24'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) >=24 AND SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) <=48 THEN '25-48'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)  >48 THEN '>48'
END) IMS_CUST_ID_GRP,  SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT), CUST_ID
FROM DEXODS.OPUB_ONE_IMS_IDS_FACT fct,
DEXWHS.D_DATE dt,
DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA ac
WHERE fct.DATE_DIM_KEY = dt.DATE_ID
AND   fct.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY = ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
AND   NEW_PAT_CNT >0
AND   dt.year in n'2016'
GROUP BY CUST_ID
```

Analytic function which returns an error

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID)   = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID)  >=2 AND        SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID)  <=12 THEN '2-12'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) >=13 AND SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) <=24 THEN '13-24'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) >=24 AND SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID)  <=48 THEN '25-48'
WHEN SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)  OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) >48 THEN '>48'
END) IMS_CUST_ID_GRP, CUST_ID, SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)
FROM DEXODS.OPUB_ONE_IMS_IDS_FACT fct,
DEXWHS.D_DATE dt,
DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA ac
WHERE fct.DATE_DIM_KEY = dt.DATE_ID
AND   fct.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY = ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
AND   NEW_PAT_CNT >0
GROUP BY CUST_ID

Dataset with CUST_ID included
IMS_CUST_ID_GRP SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)    CUST_ID
1   1   55671832
1   1   56097728
2-12    4   56106239
2-12    5   56728330
2-12    9   57590869
2-12    2   55609391
2-12    9   55880657
2-12    10  56339375
2-12    3   57371546
25-48   39  55891493
13-24   21  55714333
13-24   22  56542678

Desired Dataset rolled up to IMS_CUST_ID_GRP
IMS_CUST_ID_GRP SUM(NEW_PAT_CNT)
1                2
2-12             42
13-24            43
25-48            39
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a pivot query, using `GROUP BY`, then you don't need to use `SUM()` as an analytic function.  Just use it normally:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CUST_ID = 1 THEN NEW_PAT_CNT ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
       SUM(CASE WHEN CUST_ID >= 2  AND CUST_ID <= 12 THEN NEW_PAT_CNT ELSE 0 END) AS '2-12',
       SUM(CASE WHEN CUST_ID >= 13 AND CUST_ID <= 24 THEN NEW_PAT_CNT ELSE 0 END) AS '13-24',
       SUM(CASE WHEN CUST_ID >= 24 AND CUST_ID <= 48 THEN NEW_PAT_CNT ELSE 0 END) AS '25-48',
       SUM(CASE WHEN CUST_ID > 48  THEN NEW_PAT_CNT ELSE 0 END) AS '>48'
FROM DEXODS.OPUB_ONE_IMS_IDS_FACT fct
INNER JOIN DEXWHS.D_DATE dt
    ON fct.DATE_DIM_KEY = dt.DATE_ID
INNER JOIN DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA ac
    ON fct.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY = ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
WHERE NEW_PAT_CNT > 0      -- should not be necessary assuming count no less than zero
GROUP BY CUST_ID
```

Note that I have replaced your implicit joins with explicit `INNER JOIN`s.  As you may have heard, you should try to avoid putting commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I get a FROM keyword not expected error when running that above query.  And I also noticed the suggested query includes CUST_ID like my original query does.  I want to group by CUST_ID to get my pat count sum but use my new grouping instead (IMS_CUST_ID_GRP) to roll it up

Comment: @gisr I don't see anything wrong with my query.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?  This would be a good time to get experience in Oracle developer getting things to work.